# how to change that (www.sitename.cf/?url=ANYURL) into (ANYURL)

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/" />
```

But I want URL to be variable.

So that any URL comes after `www.sitename.cf/?url=` just opens after some time ( 5 sec ) and can I make it open as popup ?

Comment: Can you use "setTimeout" and "location.href = "? It is convenient to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked ..

```
 function params() { 
    var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
    return prmstr != null && prmstr != "" ? transformToAssocArray(prmstr) : {}; 
    }
    function transformToAssocArray( prmstr ) { var params = {}; var prmarr = prmstr.split("&"); for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) { var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("="); params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1]; } return params; } 



    setTimeout(function(){
    var url = params().url;
    url? window.location.href = url : '' ;
    },5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase `content="20";` inside `content` this is for set time.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20; url=http://example.com/"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Like @Isv mentioned, you can use Javascript for that and can remove the `meta` tag.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
}, 5000);
```

The `window.location.pathname` will give you the content after `www.sitename.cf` and will refresh the page with that URL/content.

#### Option 2

Or if you still want to use the `<meta>` tag then you still have to use Javascript:

```
var content = "5; url=" + window.location.pathname;
document.querySelector('meta[http-equiv="refresh"]').setAttribute("content", content);
```

But make sure, your initial page has an empty meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh">
```

Comment: option 1 is refreshing the same page    // option 2 not working and the meta tag is already included

Comment: option 2 is worked after editing "http-quiv" to "http-equiv" but just refreshing the same page